# How to hide zend framework2 Deprecated message

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

Deprecated: You are retrieving the service locator from within the class Admin\Controller\IndexController. Please be aware that ServiceLocatorAwareInterface is deprecated and will be removed in version 3.0, along with the ServiceLocatorAwareInitializer. You will need to update your class to accept all dependencies at creation, either via constructor arguments or setters, and use a factory to perform the injections. in /var/www/airtel-emt-credit-limit/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php on line 258

Comment: Extend the class and overwrite the function, limit `zendframework/zend-mvc` to version `2.7.8` (of the top of my head), orrrrr..... upgrade to ZF3 and solve the issues.

Comment: Please have a look at the Zend Framework migration guide. They provide a proper solution for factories. https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-servicemanager/migration/#factories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supress the warnings using [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

For example first thing in your application as in your `index.php` file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
```

All errors will be shown except for deprecated or user_deprecated.

Comment: Note that this in no way solves the problem, it just hides it. This solution should already be default on production. In development you should be solving issues and not hiding them. If OP continues to `composer update` dependencies, stuff **will** break in future.

Comment: OP asks for a way to hide it so one is provided with one. As soon as he updates his code base/dependencies he will find out soon enough that his app will no longer run.